# Loading a kernel module at boot time is blocking?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, kernel-modules

I am loading a kernel module at boot time, I added it to a config file in /etc/modules-load.d/, the module is loading correctly.

In my module I am using the wait_for_random_bytes() function from [linux/random.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/random.h), so my module can have some delay in loading.

The modules are loaded sequentially? This module of mine can delay the loading of other modules?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What the OS does ?

In my Debian (but i would bet that your CentOS just do the same), the module loading part of initialization is done by `/etc/init.d/kmod`.

Below is an extract of this script:

```
files=$(modules_files)
if [ "$files" ] ; then
  grep -h '^[^#]' $files |
  while read module args; do
    [ "$module" ] || continue
    load_module "$module" "$args"
  done
fi
```

Where:

- `modules_files` is a shell function that parses various file and directories (including `/etc/modules-load.d`) and built a list of modules to be loaded.
- `load_module` is a shell function that do the `modprobe` work + some logging if verbose flag is set.

So i would say that yes, modules are loaded sequentially and if one blocks, then it will block the other ones....

but ...

### What kernel does ?

When reading the source code of [linux/modules.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/module.c#L3779) we can see that:

- The syscall is probably implemented by the function `load_module()`. We can see that it performs a lot of stuff (initialization, memory allocation, sanity checks, signature checks, etc..) and it returns with `return do_init_module(mod);` ([line 3927](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/module.c#L3927)
- The `do_init_module()` function do at [line 3574](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/module.c#L3574) the following operation and, if everything went ok, return 0.

```
    if (mod->init != NULL)
        ret = do_one_initcall(mod->init);
    if (ret < 0) {
        goto fail_free_freeinit;
    }
```

My conclusion is the syscall will return only when:
1. The module has been loaded in memory.
2. Its init() function has ran successfully.

So if your call to `wait_for_random_bytes()` is part of the init function of your module, then yes, it may block others modules loading.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer!